# Tailwind Responsiveness working in inverse

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

Tailwind Responsiveness working in inversely

I have added the classes

```
"flex",
"justify-between",
"flex-wrap",
"items-center",
"sm:flex-col",
```

to my div and when my window loads in normal desktop view itself my sm class is getting activated and flex becomes flex-col and when I swith to responsive view of mobile it switches back to desktop view with flex-row

Why is it happening?

I was just trying to make flex row on window view and flex-col on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

It is because tailwind works on mobile first breakpoint system. In simple words it is **reverse** of bootstrap. And is working as intended.

According to [docs:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#working-mobile-first)

> By default, Tailwind uses a mobile-first breakpoint system, similar to what you might be used to in other frameworks like Bootstrap.

> What this means is that unprefixed utilities (like uppercase) take effect on all screen sizes, while prefixed utilities (like md:uppercase) only take effect at the specified breakpoint and above.

Updated code:

```
"flex",
"md:justify-between",
"md:flex-wrap",
"md:items-center",
"flex-col",
```

This will have `column` affect in any screen below `md:` breakpoint. `wrap` affect on above `md:` breakpoint